# Can Windows XP supply media to Kodi?

Tags: windows-xp, nfs, smb, kodi

I have a HTPC with XP (~ see below) and I just installed Kodi on a Raspberry Pi (LibreELEC).  A quick try with SMB didn't work, and I thought I recalled that WannaCry caused Microsoft to disable SMB, even on XP (my machine used the POS hack, so I was getting updates until recently).  [*EDIT: comments below suggest SMB was patched, not disabled*]

So I thought I'd look at NFS, but I'm not sure how to get that installed.  It seems that the "Windows Services for UNIX 3.5" might have worked, but it's no longer available anywhere that I can find.

Is there a good way to allow media on an XP machine to be used by a Kodi install across my home network?

~ Yes, it's unsupported, no, I'm not going to "upgrade" it, it's working fine, and it's on a separate network segment.

Comment: unix 3.5 for XP>>>>>https://dev.to/wincentbalin/download-link-for-microsoft-windows-services-for-unix-3-5-555p

Comment: SMBv1 was patches not disabled on vulnerable versions of Windows.  Only on currently supported versions was SMBv1 disabled by default.  Windows XP doesn’t even support anything except for SMBv1 (if it does then that’s news to me)

Comment: @Moab, Thanks for the link.  I will work-up a full answer.  Ramhound, Thanks for the clarification.  I'll edit the question soon so as to not confuse later readers.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use/enable SMB, DLNA is an option.
Windows XP doesn't have buil in DLNA, so use any free product (like this - https://github.com/ps3mediaserver/ps3mediaserver ).
On Kodi the following settings should be configured - https://kodi.wiki/view/Settings/Services/UPnP_DLNA